# How do I prevent Firefox from closing tabs on middle click?

Tags: firefox, browser, mouse, browser-tabs

This has become more of an issue since I got a Magic Mouse and have middle-click mapped as 3-finger touch. It's always annoyed me that Firefox even does this--is there a way to prevent firefox from closing tabs when you middle-click them?

Answer (score 6):

As there doesn't appear to be a setting in about:config, the only way i know how to do it is using the addon Tab Mix Plus: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122

Comment: that looks to be uber-overkill for the one thing I want to do, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Tab Mix Plus appears to have ceased development after Firefox Quantum. Is there another solution now?

Answer (score 2):

There is a long-running bug report
[Bug 1439247 : "close tab with middle click" feature is disruptive on touchpads where middle click is triggered unintentionally](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1439247)
where Firefox devs seem unable to understand the importance
of the problem. Although apparently the code to introduce such an
option was coded and ready, it was never released.

This answer uses the free [AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
on Windows. For Linux or MacOS see the post
[AutoHotkey equivalent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165124/autohotkey-equivalent).

The following example script will disable middle-click in Firefox.
I have not been able to limit it to the tabs area.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe firefox.exe
MButton::
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: If it's worth your while, do add your voice to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1439247 (""close tab with middle click" feature is disruptive on touchpads where middle click is triggered unintentionally"). Developers appear to be reluctant.

Answer (score 0):

Though I've successfully used [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/) to prevent *creating* a new tab, this answer only partially answers your question for *preventing tab closing*, and needs improvement. If someone can fix the issue that this code *prevents all* mouse events on the tab bar, *please* edit or comment.

If *userChrome.css* file is not in the Firefox profile, create it using Npotepad or other text editor. For example, in Windows, it would be in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\firefox\Profiles\<profile>.default\chrome`.

Edit *userChrome.css* to add the following lines (**N.B.** TabsToolbar seems to be case-sensitive).

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* only needed once */

/* Disable All Tab Mouse Events */
#tabbrowser-tabs .arrowscrollbox-scrollbox{pointer-events: none} .tabbrowser-tab,.tabs-newtab-button{pointer-events: none}
#TabsToolbar .toolbar-items {pointer-events: none}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a system setting not Firefox. You can check on the file explorer.

On Ubuntu 18 gnome :  `gnome-tweaks` > Windows > Titlebar Actions > Middle-Click > select Toggle Maximize

On other system : `gsettings` command line here: https://askubuntu.com/a/655648/360110

Comment: I believe the question is about browser tabs, not Gnome windows.